# i18next Error: ENOENT

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, i18next

i have this:

```
  I18N =
    detectLngQS: "lang"
    resGetPath: "locales/__lng__/__ns__.json"
    ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.layout', 'ns.forms', 'ns.msg'], defaultNs: 'ns.common'}
    ignoreRoutes: ["images/", "public/", "css/"]
    extension:".json"
    debug: false
```

in my node-express application and my locales is as follows:

```
☺  tree -L 2 locales                                                                                                                            ruby-2.0.0-p195 master 02bd09a ✗""
locales
├── README.md
├── cs-CZ
│   ├── ns.common.json
│   ├── ns.forms.json
│   ├── ns.layout.json
│   └── ns.msg.json
├── dev
│   ├── ns.common.json
│   ├── ns.forms.json
│   ├── ns.layout.json
│   └── ns.msg.json
├── en-UK
│   ├── ns.common.json
│   ├── ns.layout.json
│   └── ns.msg.json
├── fr-FR
│   ├── ns.common.json
│   ├── ns.forms.json
│   ├── ns.layout.json
│   └── ns.msg.json
└── sk-SK
    ├── ns.common.json
    ├── ns.forms.json
    ├── ns.layout.json
    └── ns.msg.json
```

i keep getting `ENOENT` messages in my console such as:

```
currentLng set to: fr-FR
loaded file: locales/fr-FR/ns.common.json
loaded file: locales/fr-FR/ns.layout.json
loaded file: locales/fr-FR/ns.forms.json
loaded file: locales/fr-FR/ns.msg.json
[ { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/fr/ns.common.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/fr/ns.common.json' },
  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/fr/ns.layout.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/fr/ns.layout.json' },
  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/fr/ns.forms.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/fr/ns.forms.json' },
  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/fr/ns.msg.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/fr/ns.msg.json' } ]
```

what am i missing?

also, in some cases, i just want to use the fallback file, so for example en-UK, i don't have the `ns.forms.json` file so i get

```
locales en-UK
loaded file: locales/en-UK/ns.common.json
loaded file: locales/en-UK/ns.layout.json
loaded file: locales/en-UK/ns.msg.json
[ { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/en/ns.common.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/en/ns.common.json' },
  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/en/ns.layout.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'locales/en/ns.layout.json' },
  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/en-UK/ns.forms.json']
    errno: 34,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'locales/en-UK/ns.forms.json' },
```

what is the correct way to fix this?

any advise much appreciated

Comment: ENOENT means it didn't find the file (entity). It looks like you have no file at `locales/en-UK/ns.forms.json` for instance. Question is, why is it looking in `/fr/` when the language  is `fr-Fr`? The easy fix to try would be to rename the `fr-Fr` directory to `fr`. Not an actual answer since I'm just taking a shot at it.

Comment: https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/blob/0a1294c506fd13819f71092ac6d91e03eb55896f/src/i18next.sync.js#L108 -- try breaking on that line and see what url it's trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is still no fix for this in the Thread and yet one of the top Google hits to the Problem here the Solution:

```
var options = {
    preload: ['en-US','de-DE'],
    fallbackLng: 'en-US',
    cookieName: 'lng',
    saveMissing: true,
    debug: true,
    resGetPath: 'locales/__lng__/__ns__.json',
    lng: 'en-US',   
    /*this is the important part*/  
    load: 'current',
    languages: ['en-US','de-DE'],
    ns: {
        namespaces: ['app','buttons'],
        defaultNs: 'app'
    }
};

i18n.init(options, function (t) {/*loaded*/});
```

If load option is set to current i18next will load the current set language (this could be a specific (en-US) or unspecific (en) resource file).

Hint: to prevent loading the fallbackLng's resource file set fallbackLng to false.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, as i was setting the code at https://github.com/nkhine/node-blade-boiler-template/blob/master/public/js/locale.js#L15 to just take the first argument, so when i change the language from the client, it was setting it as `en` instead of `en-UK` as an example.